# How do I include swscale.h in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to compile ffmpeg from source, but when I try to compile a program dependent on it ([from a tutorial](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html)), I get the error:

```
fatal error: ffmpeg/swscale.h: No such file or directory
```

I have cloned [the github repository](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg) and followed the [install instructions](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/INSTALL.md), but still get the same error.

I have also tried `make install-libs` and `make config.h`, but I'm kind of out of my depth here, because I'm not really a C programmer.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually now located in `swscale/swscale.h`, so I guess the tutorial is just outdated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `#include <libswscale/swscale.h>` if ffmpeg installed correctly (with sudo make install) and your makefile has these below:

Note: I'm using/used ffmpeg API's too, this is tested. Oh and for c++ projects you may want to use `extern "C"` before include.

Makefile (for c++):

```
LIBAV_PATH = /set_correct_pathto/ffmpeg/lib/pkgconfig/
PKG_DEPS = libavcodec libavformat libswscale libswresample libavutil
CXXFLAGS += `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(LIBAV_PATH) pkg-config --cflags $(PKG_DEPS)`
LDFLAGS  += `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$(LIBAV_PATH) pkg-config --libs $(PKG_DEPS)`
```

For C, change `CXXFLAGS` to `CFLAGS`.
Hope that helps.