# libswscale/swscale.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, ubuntu-16.04, sumo

When installing Sumo-0.30.0 on Ubuntu 16.04, `make` resulted in the following error:

```
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/<path>/sumo-0.30.0/src/gui'
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../src  -I/home/<path>/sumo-0.30.0/./src  -I/usr/include/ffmpeg -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include/fox-1.6 -I/usr/include/gdal  -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include   -msse2 -mfpmath=sse -O2 -DNDEBUG  -MT GUIViewTraffic.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/GUIViewTraffic.Tpo -c -o GUIViewTraffic.o GUIViewTraffic.cpp
In file included from GUIViewTraffic.cpp:36:0:
../../src/utils/gui/div/GUIVideoEncoder.h:58:32: fatal error: libswscale/swscale.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:449: recipe for target 'GUIViewTraffic.o' failed
```

Having installed all the prerequisite libraries as mentioned in [Installing/Linux Build Libraries](https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Installing/Linux_Build_Libraries#Ubuntu_18.04_.28tested_with_SUMO_0.32.0.29) and verifying my `ffmpeg` version is the latest one, I proceeded with `./configure` command from [installation guide](https://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Installing/Linux_Build) which was successful. The last lines of ./configure result shows that `ffmpeg` is enabled.

```
    Optional features summary
-------------------------
Enabled: TRACI PROJ GDAL GUI ffmpeg
Disabled: Debug Profiling Coverage PIC UnitTests Python OSG
```

I could neither locate `libswscale` directory nor `swscale.h` even after going through [similar post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48085911/how-do-i-include-swscale-h-in-ffmpeg).

According to another post [here](https://www.blender.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12251), someone mentions that on Ubuntu the problem is that `ffmpeg` package does not install `swscale.h`.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Install the libswscale-dev package.

Comment: Thanks @llogan. Installing this package solved the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install the [libswscale-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libswscale-dev&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) package. It provides `/usr/include/*/libswscale/swscale.h`.